# Implementing UDP Command-Acknowledge communication protocol in Node.JS and TypeScript

Tags: node.js, udp, typescript

I'm trying to implement a custom communication protocol via UDP datagrams in Node.JS and TypeScript. In this protocol I have some commands that must be sent to a microcontroller in a specific order, with every command that has to wait the ACK of the previous one from the microcontroller before it can be sent. However, given the asynchronous and "socket-centered" philosophy of Node.JS' `dgram` module, I'm having hard times in finding the correct way to implement this.

As of now, I created and `abstract class ProtocolCommand`, and various concrete children (`StartFirmwareUpgradeCommand`, `WriteCommand`, `EndFirmwareUpgradeCommand`). All the classes are consumed by a `Protocol` class that should coordinate all the commands to be executed. I'm attaching both the abstract and one example classes below. Moreover, the number of commands is variable (more specifically, after the StartFirmwareUpgrade, I have a variable number of Write commands, in which I send the firmware bytes to the microcontroller).

ProtocolCommand:

```
import q = require('q');

export abstract class ProtocolCommand {
    protected socket:dgram.Socket;
    protected ip:string;
    protected port:number;
    protected deferred;

    constructor(socket:dgram.Socket, ip:string, port:number, deferred) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.deferred = deferred;
    }

    protected callback(data, sender) {
        this.socket.removeListener('message', this.callback);
        this.deferred.resolve(data);
    }

    abstract executeCommand():void;
}
```

StartFirmwareUpgradeCommand:

```
import dgram = require('dgram');
import {ProtocolCommand} from "./ProtocolCommand";
import CRC = require('./CRC');
import q = require('q');

export class StartFirmwareUpgradeCommand extends ProtocolCommand {
    private header = [0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x19, 0x00, 0x00];
    private data = [0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36];

    constructor(socket:dgram.Socket, ip:string, port:number, deferred) {
        super(socket, ip, port, deferred);
    }

    executeCommand() {
        let commandBytes = this.header.concat(this.data);
        let crcBytes = CRC.CRC16(commandBytes);
        commandBytes = commandBytes.concat(Math.floor(crcBytes / 0x100), crcBytes % 0x100);
        this.socket.on('message', (data, sender) => {
            this.callback(data, sender);
        });
        this.socket.send(new Buffer(commandBytes), 0, commandBytes.length, this.port, this.ip);
        return this.deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

Protocol:

```
import dgram = require('dgram');
import {StartFirmwareUpgradeCommand} from "./StartFirmwareUpgradeCommand";
import {EndFirmwareUpgradeCommand} from "./EndFirmwareUpgradeCommand";
import {DiscoveryCommand} from "./DiscoveryCommand";
import q = require('q');

export class Protocol {
    private socket;
    private ip:string;
    private port:number;

    constructor(ip:string, port:number) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        this.socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
        this.socket.bind();
    }

    upgradeFirmware(data:Uint8Array) {
        let globalDeferred = q.defer();

        //FIXME UGLY AS HELL!
        new StartFirmwareUpgradeCommand(this.socket, this.ip, this.port, globalDeferred).executeCommand()
            .then((data) => {

            })
            .then((data) => {

            });
        //TODO send n*write firmware command, wait for every ack
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length / 128; i++) {

        }
        //new EndFirmwareUpgradeCommand(this.socket, this.ip, this.port).executeCommand();
        //TODO send end firmware command, wait for ack
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm currently using `q` to use promises and try to avoid callbacks as much as I can, but I'm really struggling in finding a decent way to code everything. Any help would really appreciated.

Comment: It's probably easiest to create a queue for the series of commands to be sent and each time you get a response, you send the next item in the queue.

Comment: Would you please add some reference code, so I can understand how to implement this?

Comment: I don't know TypeScript, but a queue is basically just an array of data from which you can grab the first item in the array at any time.  And, you can certainly read about a queue in a Google search.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In accordance with @gilamran's recommendation, here is an RxJS implementation.  It only waits until a response is received before sending the next request.  It doesn't handle situations where an error requires you to flush the queue.

```js
import dgram = require('dgram');
import Rx    = require('rx');   // or use rx.lite if you need something smaller.

let commandQueue = Rx.Subject();
let socket       = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
let ip           = '127.0.0.1';
let port         = '10000';

// let `req` be an object with { ip, port, header, data }.
// sendCommand :: Request -> Observable of Responses
function sendCommand (req) {
    // return this Observable so we can use Rx.Observable.concat later to
    // block while waiting for a response.
    return Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
        let   commandBytes = req.header.concat(req.data);
        const crcBytes     = CRC.CRC16(commandBytes);
        commandBytes       = commandBytes.concat(Math.floor(crcBytes / 0x100), crcBytes % 0x100);
        this.socket.on('message', (data, sender) => {
            // pass this information on for further processing?
            obs.onNext({
                data,
                sender,
            });
            obs.onCompleted();  // close this observable so `.concat` switches to next request.
        });
        socket.send(new Buffer(commandBytes), 0, commandBytes.length, req.port, req.ip)
    });
}

// ok. let's setup the downstream side of our queue.
// 1. take a request, send a packet, return an observable of one response.
// 2. wait for the observable of one response to complete.

let responses = commandQueue
    .concatMap(sendCommand);    // takes command requests and turns them into data/sender responses.

// we must subscribe to pull values through our observable chain.
responses.subscribe();

let cmdStartFirmwareUpgrade = (ip, port) => {
    return {
        ip,
        port,
        header = [0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x19, 0x00, 0x00],
        data   = [0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36],
    };
};

let cmdDiscovery = (ip, port) => { /* ... */ };
let cmdEndFirmwareUpgrade = (ip, port) => { /* ... */ };

// now let's put some commands in the queue.
commandQueue.onNext(cmdStartFirmwareUpgrade(ip, port));
commandQueue.onNext(cmdDiscovery(ip, port));
commandQueue.onNext(cmdEndFirmwareUpgrade(ip, port));
```

This example could certainly be DRY'er, but I prefer using Ramda curried functions over classes, so I left that bit out.

You can find a demo of the sequential nature of this design at https://runkit.com/boxofrox/rxjs-queue .

Comment: Thanks for having spent your time in writing a detailed answer with rx.js. However, since this was my first attempt to understand procedural programming properly and since the tool I'm writing should be a quick "code-and-forget" tool, I decided to implement a simple recursive queue with promises. Anyway, your answer will be a lot useful to me in the future, since there will be a time in my near future in which I could use rx.js in a (really) more complex scenario, so again, thank you and @gilamran for introducing it to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using `q` here will not serve you well, this is why:

`q` is intended for helping your library users use your library in an async way. Is it intended more as a "nice" way to let your users know when something is done. and then do something else that they want to do (In their code).

But when building a protocol, you don't want to do .then everywhere, especially if you don't know what's coming next.

What to use?
I trully recommend `rxjs` here, it's using observables and it'll be much more intuitive to implement each command. It will also be very easy to create a queue out of all your commands and run over all of them in a (async) loop way.

You can watch few minutes about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOOT7BArVHQ&t=318). (Don't worry about all the Angular things there)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it ASAP.